# jQuery hidden iframe File upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We're attempting to upload a file using a hidden iframe and the script runs in all browsers except IE(9).

- The user clicks on a link
- Link triggers file input to open
- File input change triggers form submit
- Form submits to iframe

IE9 developer tool returns the following error message:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
jquery-latest.js, line 2977 character 6
```

Looking around, it seems to be an error that occurs alongside the jQuery `change()` event. Fairly sure it must be a simple solution... Many thanks if you are able to help!

**HTML**

```
<form class="hidden" action="index.php?upload" method="POST" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden_iframe">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userFile">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<iframe id="hidden_iframe" class="hidden" name="hidden_iframe" src="inc/temp.html"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#fake').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#userFile').click();
    return false;
});
$('#real').on("change",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the deprecated `.live()` but the newer `.on()`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Doesn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider an alternate solution altogether?

Uploading through a hidden iframe isn't the best way to do this nowadays.

Have a look at this awesome lib instead: http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: Could be a solution; totally unsure of how to use it in the same context though (we're using a polling upload bar for example).

Comment: Using the plupload, you'll get a real upload bar and not the polling almost-true progress bar. Check out the examples. They will blow you away! They even have drag and drop support (like gmail etc). And you will have it running in no time. And no, I am not affiliated with the project :)

Comment: I used the custom example to make my implementation: http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php

Comment: Many thanks! :) I'll post the final script for further help of others.

Comment: are you aware of how to check when the script it has been passed to has successfully completed (JSON-style)?

Comment: In normal `$.post()` you can provide callback functions that will execute when the request is complete. However, for plupload, they have wrapped things and they raise an event when the upload is complete. You make use of it like this `uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) { console.log(up); console.log(file); })`.
Docs: http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html

Answer (score 1):

This is IE security setting. Just go to Settings->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level and change security settings under "Miscellaneous" set "Access data sources across domains" to Enable.

EDIT:

I just saw what's the problem. You're triggering the file upload and you're not allowed to do that. You need to let the user *manually* click the file-selector button.

Comment: This wouldn't be a good way of "solving" the problem as you can't expect every user to change their settings. **Are you aware of any go-arounds of this?**

Comment: Also just FYI, this doesn't stop the problem.

Comment: In fact, this should happen only if you're uploading the file to a different domain than the domain you're running the script on. So that means no pop-ups and no localhost-to-server uploads (and obviously no cross-site uploads)

Comment: Same directory, same server. Any ideas?

Comment: Yep- that's the issue outlined in the question, but I want this triggered- possible without errors?

Comment: Nop, that's a security setting, you can't overide it, sorry.